# What is the largest size m on input that can be solved in 1s?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

The computational complexity of some algorithm A is O(n*sqrt(n)). The time needed to execute an elementary operation is 1 ms. What is the largest size s of input that can be solved in 1s. How many times larger is the largest size of input if we use a 1000 times faster computer ? Explain your answer.

I ran into this question in an algorithm's book, it's supposed to be a theoretical question, however i can't find materials in the book to help solve this. Could anybody provide an explanation or hints.

I don't want to edit the original question, however would it make more sense to use Big-Theta Ө(n*sqrt(n)) instead of Big-O ?

Comment: That's an ill-posed question. Big-O notation does not give any hint about absolute timing. Hence, you do not know how many elementary operations there are (may be `n*sqrt(n)` or `10000 * n * sqrt(n)` or any other function that belongs to the set described by `O(n sqrt(n))`).

Comment: I wouldn't know how to reply in all honesty, i simply posted the question as i found it. What if we write f(n) <= c*(n*sqrt(n)) ?

Comment: This question makes no sense in a lot of ways. How do you define an "elementary" operation? What's a "faster" computer? I'd say drop the book and study on another one.

Comment: After posting this question, i most likely will!

Comment: You will still run till the end of the universe for O( lg N ) for N >= 2^2^1000000..00, so no you are not talking about absolute time when using Big-O

Comment: also there is the problem on nowadays architectures that even if you obtain the constant factors for implementation of algorithm the "constant time" coefficients change with the size of data or number of instructions processed due to CACHE so without knowing what is saturated state (which is usually really hard to predict) is any calculation of runtime meaningless that is why the runtime should be measured instead of deduced from Big `O`.

Comment: Would the question make more sense if we had Big-Theta instead ?, meaning we would have a tight bound instead of an upper bound. At-least that's what i managed to deduce from the explanation on the book, and i'm assuming they typed the wrong notation.

Comment: Such complexity could not exactly predict algorithm running time on a given machine, it just gives you hints about overall running time behavior over different runs. Only exact complexity could but this is another matter... You may only roughly estimate the constant C... But you can compare differential in times for 1x and 1000x the same computer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an algorithm has

```
O(n*sqrt(n))
```

time complexilty it actually means that executing time is

```
T(n) = C*n*sqrt(n) + o(n*sqrt(n))
```

Where `C` is some constant. For instance, `T(n)` can well be

```
T(n) = 1000 * n * sqrt(n) + 1e10 * n + 200 * sqrt(n) + 15 * log(n) + 1e20
```

Of course, the formula above is an exaggeration, but, you see the
problem: `O(f(n))` is not *execution time itself*, but its *asymptotic* only. To approximate the execution time you have to carry out experiment, e.g. if we have

```
   n | T(n), ms
 --------------
   1 |       12
   3 |       20
  10 |       73
  30 |      339
 100 |     2010
```

we can approximate `T(n)` with a help of minimal squares algorithm as

```
 T(n) = 2 * n * sqrt(n) + 10
```

when having the formula you can solve it for `n`. In the example above

```
   2 * n * sqrt(n) + 10 = 1000
```

we can find out

```
   n = 495**(2/3) = 63
```

as the maximum size of the problem which can be solved in `1000` milliseconds.

When having just `O(f(n))` you can't (in *general case*) say what'll happen with the execution time if you have a faster computer, but evident "it won't be worse". Let's return to our exaggerated formula:

```
T(n) = 1000 * n * sqrt(n) + 1e10 * n + 200 * sqrt(n) + 15 * log(n) + 1e20
```

as you can see, in the Real World it's the last item - **1e20** that dominates for all the reasonable inputs that's why the answer will be "1000 times faster workstation will change *nothing*". On the contrary:

```
T(n) = 1e-1000 * n * sqrt(n) + log(n)
```

has `O(n*sqrt(n))` complexity with `log(n)` item dominating for the *reasonable* (i.e. *small enough*) `n`s; `1000` times CPU performance increase will result in `2**1000 == 1e300` increase of the algorithm's perfomance.

Answer (score 3):

The question is bogus in two ways:

- asymptotic complexities have an implicit multiplicative constant which is unknown. It is wrong to say "time is O(N) -> N operations are performed";
- O(N) is just an upper bound, a guarantee that the time will not exceed C.N for some C. But in fact it tells you nothing about the actual running time !

Now to make the question a little more solvable, we will assume

- that the running time is exactly C.N√N,
- that C=1 ms.

Then N√N = 1000 when N = 100 and N√N = 1000000 when N = 10000.

Comment: Shame on who designed the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Big-Oh notation is wrong to use here. You don't know how many elementary operations there are per `n` because Big-Oh drops all constant factors and all lower-order terms. These functions are all in `O(n*sqrt(n))`:

```
f(n) = n * sqrt(n)
g(n) = 4711 * n * sqrt(n)
h(n) = n * sqrt(n) + 18 650 000 000
```

If we *assume* they mean the first function (a bad assumption), then your first question is nothing more than solving the simple algebraic expression for `n`:

```
1000 = f(n) = n * sqrt(n)
```

But the question might be a trick question so making this assumption would be wrong. Try to solve for `n` using `g(n)` and `h(n)` and you will get widely different answers.